# How to set SoapProcessing via code

Tags: c#, wcf, binding, behavior

I'm trying to disable SoapProcessing for an endpoint (yes, it needs to be done, don't ask why, and message inspectors will not work):

[MSDN docs for soapProcessing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee816919%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

However, all of the documentation I've found seems to rely on setting this value in the app's config file. I am developing a plugin for an application that does not allow me to include a separate config file, so I have to set up the endpoint and bindings and all that via code:

```
// Create transport binding
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential);
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName;

// Create client
MySyncPortClient _service = new MySyncPortClient(binding, new EndpointAddress("https://path/to/service"));
_service.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "foo";
_service.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "bar";

// Set custom bindings
BindingElementCollection elements = _service.Endpoint.Binding.CreateBindingElements();
elements.Find<SecurityBindingElement>().IncludeTimestamp = false;
_service.Endpoint.Binding = new CustomBinding(elements);

// Perform a request
_service.DoSomething();
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it. And not to be rude, but please do not suggest using a config file. It -NEEDS- to be done via code. If you want a full explanation, I can provide one separately.

Comment: I get why you can't do it in the plug-in config file, but are you ruling out making the change in the config file of the application into which the plug-in is plugging-in?

Comment: Ok, but doing it in the caller's config file is what allows different configurations for each caller. Your callers will not be able to change the configuration.

Comment: I understand, but this plugin gets deployed as a single DLL file to an application that automatically downloads a new config file from the server if it detects any changes, so there's no way to either deploy/provide a separate config file nor modify the main app's config file. It all -has- to be done via code.

Comment: I'm still not getting this. Shouldn't your config be included with the downloaded config, so that the configuration can be changed and automatically downloaded? Or do they not use standard .NET techniques for their config file?

Comment: Nope. As I said, it HAS to be done via code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing this out - apparently it can't be done.